# contar si un numero de una lista es menor a un numero dado en prolog

Tags: prolog

Hola verán el problema es que dado por ejemplo una lista [1,9,3,5,2,6,4,7,8]
este tome cada valor de la lista y diga si cuando aparece este numero N tiene adelante algun valor menor a el y los contará donde al final se sumará todo

- no hay números menores después = 0
- 9 (Vacío) - tiene al 3,5,2,6,4,7,8 posteriormente = 7
- 3 - tiene al 2 posteriormente = 1
- 5 - tiene al 2,4 posteriormente = 2
- 2 - no tiene números menores que lo sucedan = 0
- 6 - tiene al 4 posteriormente = 1
- 4 - no tiene números menores después = 0
- 7 - no tiene números menores después = 0
- 8 - no tiene números menores después = 0

al final sumando todo eso daria 11

Esta es la función que cree

```
menores(X,[],Aux):- Aux is 0+0.
menores(X,[H|T],Cuenta):- X>H-> Aux is 1+0; Aux is 0+0, menores(X,T,Aux), Cuenta is Aux.
```

pero estos han sido los resultados

```
?- 
|    menores(1,[9,3,5,2,6,4,7,8],POP).
POP = 0 .

?- menores(3,[5,2,6,4,7,8],POP).
POP = 0.
```

debería dar en la segunda un 1 ya que esta función es la primera parte que compara cada valor si es menor y cuantos y se lo retornará a una funcion que acumulará y será la encargada de ir sacando la cabeza y llamando a esta funcion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una implementacion sencilla, espero te sirva para poder empezar:

```
menores(_, [], 0).
menores(Num, [H|B], Menores):- Num > H, menores(Num, B, Retorno), Menores is Retorno + 1.
menores(Num, [H|B], Menores):- Num < H, menores(Num, B, Menores).
menores(Num, [Num|B], Menores):- menores(Num, B, Menores).
```

aquí se compara el valor `Num` con el primero de la lista, si es mayor se suma uno, si no se sigue tomando los valores de la lista (lo mismo si son valores iguales).

Answer (score 0):

en verdad funciona, la sentencia de if me confundio un poco, de relacinado me salio que alguien queria saber la cantidad de numeros mayores de un numero N en una lista y tome su codigo y lo adapte a mi casa y se me practicamente igual al tuyo:

```
menor(_,[],0).
menor(N,[H|Q],X):- N>H, menor(N,Q,X1), X is X1+1.
menor(N,[H|Q],X):- N<H, menor(N,Q,X).
```

Ahora estoy haciendo una función que calculara la distancia manhattan , donde por ejemplo en la matriz [[1,9,3],[5,2,6],[4,7,8]] tengo que hallar la casilla nueve "que es una casilla vacia" y ver que se encuentra en la coordenada (1,2) y aplicar esto:

d = abs(3-1) + abs(3-2) = 3

abs se que es una función ya definida en prolog, pero recibir una lista de listas y ver sus coordenadas es lo que estoy pensando, conoces alguna nocion de como podria hacerla?

***Matemáticamente, si tomamos dos puntos p y q en una cuadrícula con coordenadas p=(p1,p2) y q=(q1,q2), la distancia Manhattan entre dichos puntos es la suma de los valores absolutos de las diferencias entre las coordenadas. Es decir:
d(p,q)=|q1-p1|+|q2-p2|***